# Shared Element Transition overloapping BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I used SharedElement Transition to go DetailsActivity in my recyclerView's onItemClick method. But when the item which is at the bottom is clicked it first it gets on top op BottomNavigationView an then Transition happens. OnBackPressed it is the same. Also it get ons top of mechanic keys in emulator. How to fix it?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
   >

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/childofMain"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottom_navigation_view">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainRecyclerView"

    >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:titleEnabled="false"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="94dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mainRecyclerView"
        >

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"

            />

            <ImageView android:layout_width="120dp"
                       android:layout_height="36dp"
                       android:id="@+id/mainOdulluDUzyazi"
                       android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                       android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                       app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/trendyarismalar"
                      android:text="Trend Yarışmalar"
                      android:textColor="@color/white"
                      android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                      android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                      android:textSize="20sp"
                      android:textStyle="bold"
                      app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mainRecyclerView"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:behavior_overlapTop="150dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:itemIconSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="5dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"


>
</com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use this;

```
<item name="android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay">false</item>
```

**Note:** Put this line to your application base theme inside styles.xml file.